# Como criar um custom model field herdando ForeignKey no Django?

Tags: django, orm

Estou querendo construir um model field customizado que se comporte como ForeignKey, só que com alguns detalhes adicionais.

Esse campo customizado irá cadastrar automaticamente um documento, passando como referencia o nome do modelo. Sendo assim, se eu estiver cadastrando uma pessoa, será gerado um documento para ela, e neste documento será registrado o nome do modelo, no caso Pessoa.

**Exemplo:**

```
# esse model 'documento' seria utilizado como referencia para qualquer outro model
class Documento(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class CustomDocForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):
    pass
    # relacionado a Documento
    # if este campo estiver vazio então crie um documento:
    #    nome_da_class_origem = ? # ex: Pessoa, Carro, ...
    #    doc = Documento.objects.create(modelo=nome_da_class_origem)
    #    return doc

class Pessoa(models.Model):
    documento = CustomDocForeignKey()

class Carro(models.Model):
    documento = CustomDocForeignKey()

class Animal(models.Model):
    documento = CustomDocForeignKey()
```

Com esse custom model field seria gerado automaticamente um documento para esta pessoa ou carro ou animal, caso não tenha nenhum documento. Além disso, é passado o nome do model `__class__.__name__` para ser armazenado no campo `modelo` da class `Documento`.

PS: a ideia é que esse campo seja preenchido ao ser chamado o método save(), assim como o `auto_now_add=True` do campo `DateField`.

Comment: No caso não precisaria herdar de ForeignKey , bastaria usar um campo nos modelos que são ForeignKey para o documento.

documento = models.ForeignKey(CustomDoc)

1. Usa mixin para não se repetir.. , dentro do mixin , no __init__ dela passa uma classe para ser gravado.